# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: Swift, Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8.3

I am getting error on the line:
`let indexPath = self.menuTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()!`. 
Seems that I am not getting a value from `indexPathForSelectedRow`. I am parsing from a `CSV` file into `Core Data`. Not sure if it matters. I am new to coding, so not sure if I am missing something obvious.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var menuTable: UITableView!
    private var menuItems:[MenuItem] = []
    var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load menu items from database
        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MenuItem")
            var e: NSError?
            menuItems = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &e) as! [MenuItem]
            if e != nil {
                println("Failed to retrieve record: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        // Make the cell self size
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 66.0
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return menuItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = menuTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.nameLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].detail
//        cell.priceLabel.text = "$\(menuItems[indexPath.row].price as! Double)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showFront", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "showFront")
        {
            var upcoming: CardFrontViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CardFrontViewController

            let indexPath = self.menuTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

            let titleString = menuItems[indexPath.row].name

            upcoming.titleStringViaSegue = titleString

            self.menuTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the cell in your storyboard connected to a segue?

Comment: Yes, I have the cell connected to a storyboard segue, "Show (e.g. Push)" with identifier "showFront".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and the cell is connected to the segue in the storyboard, the segue is happening twice.  The second time the segue is performed there would be no selection because you deselect it during the first segue.  You can fix this issue by deleting your implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or by creating the segue in the storyboard with the view controller itself as the source instead of the cell and leaving your manual invocation of the segue.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I deleted the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: as you suggested and it worked!

Comment: @Sara Glad to worked.  You might consider marking the answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem but why are u using self as sender if u need the indexPath?

Try:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showFront", sender: indexPath)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "showFront")
        {
            var upcoming: CardFrontViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CardFrontViewController


            let titleString = menuItems[indexPath.row].name

            upcoming.titleStringViaSegue = titleString

            self.menuTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }
    }
```

Comment: What would be an alternative way if I don't use self as sender? I am new to this. And I thought this is the best way?...

Comment: 'override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "showFront")
        {
            var upcoming: CardFrontViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CardFrontViewController
            
            let indexPath = menuTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            
            let titleString = menuItems[indexPath.row].name
            
            upcoming.titleStringViaSegue = titleString
            
            self.menuTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            
        }
    }
'

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a `UITableViewController`. In a `UITableViewController` a `UITableView` is automatically created for you with the needed outlets. You can access it in code via `self.tableView`. My guess is that you do not connected the `IBOutlet` for your `UITableView` called `menuTable`. So the optional which is nil while unwrapping is not the `indexPath` but the `UITableView`.

**Fix:**
Delete your `IBOutlet` and everywhere you use the `menuTable` variable and use `self.tableView` instead.

Comment: I deleted my IBOutlet and used self.tableView instead. But I received the same error...

Comment: '  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "showFront")
        {
            var upcoming: CardFrontViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CardFrontViewController
            
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            
            let titleString = menuItems[indexPath.row].name
            
            upcoming.titleStringViaSegue = titleString
            
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            
        }
    }
}
'